# Error having ; in str_replace array?

Tags: php, str-replace

This gives me error

```
$illegal = array("&", "<", ">", "\");
$legal = array("&amp;", "&lt;", "&gt;", "&quot;");

$row['name'] = str_replace($illegal, $legal, $row['name']);
```

this is the main part of the code

```
$xml_output = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n";
$xml_output .= "<products>\n";

for($x = 0 ; $x < mysql_num_rows($resultID) ; $x++){
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultID);
    $xml_output .= "\t<product>\n";
    $xml_output .= "\t\t<id>" . $row['id'] . "</id>\n";
        // Escaping illegal characters
$illegal = array("&", "<", ">", "\");
$legal = array("&amp;", "&lt;", "&gt;", "&quot;");

$row['name'] = str_replace($illegal, $legal, $row['name']);


    $xml_output .= "\t\t<name>" . $row['name'] . "</name>\n";
    $xml_output .= "\t</product>\n";
}

$xml_output .= "</products>";

echo $xml_output;
```

My 2 questions are

1. Is the first block of code that works, faster or equal to the second?
2. If the second block is faster, how can I fix it ?

Thank you.

Comment: The fact that syntax highlighting is broken on your post should point you to one of the issues.

Comment: `$illegal = array("&", "<", ">", "\");` Missing a second quote at `"\"`. You could just do `'"'` instead of `"\""`.

Comment: You seem to have lost a quotation mark: `$illegal = array("&", "<", ">", "\");` should have `"\""` instead of `"\"`, as in the older version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$illegal = array("&", "<", ">", "\");
```

should be

```
$illegal = array("&", "<", ">", '"');
```

Furthermore, have a look at using [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) instead of your own solution.

Comment: Based on `"&quot;"`, he wants a quote `"\""`, not a slash `"\\"`.

Comment: Thanks. +1 for mentioning `htmlspecialchars()` and for using single quotes

Comment: @Nikolai: No, You would want `"\""`, my first solution was a mistake from misreading your question.

Answer (score 0):

for Question 1: You can test your runtime speed using microtime()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php

```
<?php
    $time_start = microtime(true);

    // your code

    $time_end = microtime(true);
    $time = $time_end - $time_start;

    echo $time;
?>
```